# How to split left data as keys and right data ask values in perl

Tags: perl

my input file:

```
Lin :202020 123 455
Star :21334 1233 555
```

I'm trying to split Lin & Star as keys and the rest of the numbers as values.
However, I'm getting output like this :

```
'202020 123 455 Star' => undef,
```

my expected output :

```
$VAR1 = {
'Lin' =>'202020 123 455',
'Star'=>'21334 1233 555'
}
```

My code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
.
.
.
.
while($lines)
{
my %hash = split /[:]/,$lines;
print Dumper (%hash);
last;
}
```

Comment: show the code that sets $lines and its content

Comment: Can you post your *real* code, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problems with your code:

1. We don't know what `$lines` is
2. `while ($lines)` doesn't make any sense
3. You're re-initializing `%hash` on every iteration of the loop
4. `last` doesn't make any sense

Solution:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my %hash;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @parts = split(/\s*:\s*/);
    $hash{$parts[0]} = $parts[1];
}

print Dumper(\%hash);

__DATA__
Lin :202020 123 455
Star :21334 1233 555
```

Comment: I'd probably add some optional whitespace to the split: `/\s*:\s*/` since the whitespace disappears in the desired output.

Comment: @briandfoy That's fair. Edited my answer to account for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
use 5.18.2;
use strict ;
use warnings ;
use Data::Dumper;

my @Data = ( "Lin :202020 123 455" , "Star :21334 1233 555" ) ;
my %hash = map { (split(':'))[0] => (split(':'))[1] } @Data ; # you can also use <STDIN> instead of @Data                                             
print Dumper(\%hash);
```